ArrayList sublist method clarification
This is regarding the usage of subList method in an ArrayList.
Consider I am having an array as below:-
int[] prices = {71,11,65,99,21,82};

I am converting the above array to arrayList as below:-
List<Integer> priceList = Arrays.stream(prices).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Now, I want to retrieve the elements from position 3 till end and I apply the sublist as follows:-
priceList.subList(3, priceList.size());
            
for(Integer price: priceList) {
    System.out.println(price);
}

But I am still getting the entire list as output. I thought the arrays.stream.boxed would have returned an unmodifiable list and I tried to change as
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream....)

But still, I am getting the same output.
Could someone please help with this issue?

This really seems like it would be a duplicate but I cannot find an original.

@BIBOOunit - "returns to you a copy of the list" is not accurate, can be misleading - it returns a view, that is, changes in one list will be reflected on the other list

@user3153356 BTW, if you want to change the original list, that is, remove the first 3 elements, you can do priceList.subList(0,3).clear() (based on my previous comment and assuming that the list has at least 3 elements)

complement to my last comment: also assuming that the list is modifiable - not guaranteed by Collectors.toList()!

By the way, in more recent versions of Java you can shorten .collect(Collectors.toList()) to .toList().

First thing, the method subList won't modify the reference on which it is invoked. That means when you call priceList.subList(3, priceList.size()) the priceList isn't getting modified instead, the method returns a new List based on the range. Since you didn't assign it to a variable you cannot access it. So, when you invoke subList method you will have two lists one will be the main list (priceList which won't be modified) and a new subList.
Approach-1
Assign the sub list to a new variable/reference, that way you can use that list in the later portions of the code
List<Integer> subList = priceList.subList(3, priceList.size());
        
for(Integer price : subList) {
    System.out.println(price);
}

Approach-2
If you don't want the sublist in the later portions of your code, supply the return of the subList method to the for-each loop.
for(Integer price : priceList.subList(3, priceList.size())) {
    System.out.println(price);
}


subList does not modify
As commented, the List#subList method does not modify the original list. That method returns a new List object.
Beware: That new second list is actually a view onto the first. Changes to the original will be perceived in the second. The new second list is not separate and distinct from the original.
When programming, you must read the documentation carefully to decipher what a class and method actually do, not what you intuit they do. To quote the Javadoc:

Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. … The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

Change your code to capture the new list being returned.
List<Integer> partialPriceList = priceList.subList( 3 , priceList.size() );
            
for ( Integer price : partialPriceList ) {
    System.out.println( price );
}

If you want a separate list, pass the second list to the constructor of a third list.
List<Integer> independentPartialPriceList =
    new ArrayList<>( priceList.subList( 3 , priceList.size() ) ) ;

Stream
By the way, streams makes for simpler code in your situation. See IntStream.
Arrays.stream( prices ).skip( 3 ).forEach( System.out :: println ) ;


@user85421 Yes.  Thanks for the correction.

First Convert to Array list, then get the subset to another list, then you can print, that way you will have your outcome
List<Integer> priceList = Arrays.stream(prices).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> subList = priceList.subList(3, priceList.size());

for (Integer price : subList) {
   System.out.println(price);
}



Much simpler:
final List<Integer> list = java.util.Arrays.asList(71, 11, 65, 99, 21, 82);
final List<Integer> sublist = list.subList(3, list.size());


please note that Arrays.asList() returns a fixed-size list, that is, elements can be changed but no additional element can be added neither can any element be removed
